# How do I add the Google MyBusiness C# Client Library in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-api-client

There seems to be some issue with downloading the C# library. How do I get it added to the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add all these projects to the solution.
 Then you can create a new program(such as console app), and right click add reference-> choose projects.

The following is the detailed steps.

1.Right click the solution->adding existing project->adding the project that you have downloaded from the link.

2.Create a new program that you will use google API->add reference-> projects ->choose the project you added last step.

3.Now you could use the class and method in the app.